# Linq GroupBy query syntax equivalent

Tags: c#, linq

I write query with method syntax where I use GroupBy than I can select list:

```
var q = foo.Join(ext, o => o.Id, i => i.fooId, (o, i) => new { tFirst = o, tSecond = i })
    .GroupBy(p => p.tFirst, p => p.tSecond, (key, g) => new { tFirst = key, tSecondList = g.ToList() })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        FooId = x.tFirst.Id, // I can select Id
        Other = x.tFirst.Other, //and I can select other properties
        Values = x.tSecondList.Select( ... ) // here I can select list
    }
```

then I try to write this with query syntax but solution like this didn't worked:

```
var q = from f in foo
        join e in ext on f.Id equals e.fooId
        group new { e } by new { f, e.fooId } into g
```

How to write query syntax with group by so I finally can choose a list like in first snippet?

Comment: You can use `select new { FooId = g.Key.Id, Other = g.Key.Other, Values = g.Select() }`. Depending on what EF you are using, your `ToList` may be causing client side evaluation, in which case you may need `Values = g.ToList().Select()`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```cs
var q = 
    from f in foo
    join e in ext on f.Id equals e.fooId
    group e by new { f.Id, e.fooId } into g
    select new 
    {
        FooId = g.Key.Id,
        Values = g.Select(x => ...).ToList()
    }
```

Comment: I clarified my question because in first method syntax I can select more properties from tFirst.

Comment: In LINQ query syntax you also can do that. If you post concrete classes - you’ll get better result